# How can I ignore SSL checks while using Webclient in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, ssl

I am trying to get the contents of this URL as a string.

https://noembed.com/embed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FLhOGOg2Qg

This is the code I am using:

```
        var html_content = "";

        using (var client = new WebClient())

        {


            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36");

            html_content += client.DownloadString("https://noembed.com/embed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FLhOGOg2Qg");


        }
        Console.WriteLine(html_content);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

And this is the error I get:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
  Source=System
```

I am using this on a WPF application and I am OK with ignoring SSL here. I have already tried other answers for ignoring SSL but none worked. It works with other urls, eg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FLhOGOg2Qg but not with the noembed.com URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; 
this worked for me :

```
var html_content = "";
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        using (var client = new WebClient())

        {


            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36");

            html_content += client.DownloadString("https://noembed.com/embed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FLhOGOg2Qg");


        }
        Console.WriteLine(html_content);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

output i got :

{"author_url":"https://www.youtube.com/user/nogoodflix","url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FLhOGOg2Qg","provider_url":"https://www.youtube.com/","title":"ONE FOR THE MONEY Trailer 2011 Official [HD] Katherine Heigl","author_name":"Streaming Clips","type":"video","height":270,"thumbnail_height":360,"thumbnail_width":480,"provider_name":"YouTube","html":"\nhttps://www.youtube.com/embed/1FLhOGOg2Qg?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\">\n","thumbnail_url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1FLhOGOg2Qg/hqdefault.jpg","version":"1.0","width":480}